# How Do I Create a Series of Buttons Using php While Loop?

Tags: php, html

I want to create 4 buttons in a horizontal row. I'm using a variable to set the 'x' coordinate.

I have this code.

```
<?php
$x=0;
while ($x<1000)
{
  echo $x;
  echo '<div style="position: absolute;top: 0; left: '.$x.';width: 200px;">
  <button style="width: 200px; height: 125px" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'" class="w3-button w3-red"></button>
  </div>';
  $x=$x+250;
}
?>
```

But it only displays one button and not the 4 I'm expecting. I can't see where the problem is...

Comment: Its showing 4 buttons if I execute. please check once more. Or clear your cache.

Comment: Have you come up with something or not ?

Comment: The answer below sorted it.

Comment: cool (y)........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a px after left:

```
echo '<div style="position: absolute;top: 0; left: '.$x.'px;width: 200px;">
```

```html
<div class="section result" style="margin-top:80px;">
  0
  <div style="position: absolute;top: 0; left: 0;width: 200px;">
    <button style="width: 200px; height: 125px" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-red">1</button>
  </div>250
  <div style="position: absolute;top: 0; left: 250px;width: 200px;">
    <button style="width: 200px; height: 125px" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-red">2</button>
  </div>500
  <div style="position: absolute;top: 0; left: 500px;width: 200px;">
    <button style="width: 200px; height: 125px" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-red">3</button>
  </div>750
  <div style="position: absolute;top: 0; left: 750px;width: 200px;">
    <button style="width: 200px; height: 125px" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-red">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```